# Calling external command in Python

Tags: python

i have an XML file, I recovered from ftp. i want to convert this xml to json
i use the xml2json

How can I call an external command  from within a Python script?

***python script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ftplib
import os

# Connection information
server = 'xxxxxx.xxxx'
username = 'xxxxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxxxx'

# Directory and matching information
directory = '/datas/'
filematch = '*.xml'
src='/opt/scripts/'
dst='/opt/data/'

# Establish the connection
ftp = ftplib.FTP(server)
ftp.login(username, password)

# Change to the proper directory
ftp.cwd(directory)

# Loop through matching files and download each one individually
for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
    fhandle = open(filename, 'wb')
    print 'Getting ' + filename
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)
    fhandle.close()

#?????????????????? EXECUTE XML2JSON TO CONVERT MY XML INTO JSON ???????????????????????
#?????????????????? xml2json -t xml2json -o stockvo.json stockvo.xml --strip_text ?????????????

#move the stockvo.xml file to destination
os.system('mv %s %s' % (src+'stockvo.xml', dst+'stockvo.xml'))

#remove the src file 
os.unlink(src+'stockvo.xml')
```

Comment: You can use the `subprocess.call` function from `subprocess` module.

Comment: Did you try a shell script?

Comment: @Tichodroma no how can i try this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) has a function for that.

You could do something like:

```
 import subprocess

 subprocess.call('xml2json -t xml2json -o stockvo.json stockvo.xml --strip_text', shell=True)
```

Please note that using the `shell=True` option can be a security hazard, but that depends on what you will do with your script and whether a potential user could try to do [shell injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) on it.

**Edit**: As @PadraicCunningham suggested, there's no need to use `shell=True` actually, since you're not using shell utilities as wildcards or `~` for home expansion. So it should work only like:

```
subprocess.call('xml2json -t xml2json -o stockvo.json stockvo.xml --strip_text')
```

Comment: There is no reason to use shell=True, you should also use check_call

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you're right, you can also use `check_call`, and it's true that `shell=True` is not really needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

 subprocess.call(['xml2json', '-t', 'xml2json', '-o', 'stockvo.json', 'stockvo.xml', '--strip_text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module:

> **subprocess.check_call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
>   shell=False)**'
>   Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete.
>   If the return code was zero then return, otherwise raise
>   `CalledProcessError`. The `CalledProcessError` object will have the return
>   code in the returncode attribute.

```
import subprocess

try:
    subprocess.check_call(['xml2json', '-t', 'xml2json', '-o', 'stockvo.json', 'stockvo.xml' '--strip_text'])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass  # handle failure here
```